# ViewController gets deallocated which leads to crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting

I have a view in my storyboard which I assigned an identifier called "MainView". However if I add its view to the subview, everything that follows produces a crash (e.g. pressing a button)

```
MainViewController *mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainView"];
             [self.view addSubview:mvc.view];
```

This is the action triggered by the button : **(MainViewController.h)**

```
-(IBAction)showUsername:(id)sender{

    [testLabel setText:@"username"];

}
```

and the crash log :

```
-[MainViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x44e0810
```

**I use ARC.**

Comment: instantiateViewControllerWithIentifier: creates an autoreleased object. You have to `-retain` it here, and `-release it when it's not needed anymore.

Comment: I use ARC, so calling `retain` is not supported ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way to deal with this is using a property. Here's how:

In your .h file:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MyClass : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) MainViewController *mvc;

@end
```

In your .m file:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize mvc;

// Your code here
- (void)yourMethodHere {
    self.mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainView"];
    [self.view addSubview:mvc.view];
}
```

Comment: I have considered doing that, but I use ARC, so I can't really call retain on any object.

Comment: Scratch what I said... Using a property will avoid the problem you're running into.

Comment: Although this avoids the problem, can anyone explain why this is happening?