# Keep a storyboard's UITableViewController running while it's not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've recently entered the iOS developing scene. I have coded my first app, which is suppoused to alert you when you enter a certain location using geofences.

My app consists of a storyboard, with three Views:

- ToDoListTableViewController
- AddToDoItemViewController
- GeofenceTableViewController

The GeofenceTableViewController.m file has the code to create, edit and delete geofences. It also has the code that produces a notification whenever a geofence is entered or exited. This is working okay, I've tested it several times.

Here's the problem: 
 Whenever I'm in the iOS simulator, as long as I'm viewing the GeofenceTableViewController view, the app produces the notifications and writes to the debug log as expected, but if I'm viewing any of the two other views and I change the simulator's location, nothing happens on the app.

So what I'd like to know is, how to keep GeofenceTableViewController methods running even when that class is not what's visible on the iOS simulator screen.

Here's a video showing how when I'm on a specific view, and I change xcode's location, the app creates a notification (with a 3 sec. delay), and when I'm on another view (when I press the "Products" button), and change xcode's location, the app won't create a notification unless I re-enter the "Locations" view (when I press the + symbol at the bottom).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5taaO8UAiLc

Is there something very general I'm missing? Or do you guys need to see the code in order to help me out?

Please let me know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rdelmar I control-dragged the + symbol button to the GeofenceTableViewController, and selected PUSH. I guess that's called a Push Segue? Doing that automatically created a "Back" button in the GeofenceTableViewController, which is what I use to go back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to keep that controller (Geofence) from being deallocated. How you do that depends on your controller hierarchy, but some object needs to keep a strong pointer to it. If it is pushed or presented from AddToDoItemViewController, then that controller should have a property that points to it, and only instantiate the controller once the first time it pushes or presents it: you would have to do a manual presentation or push, not do it with a segue since they always instantiate new controllers. Of course, if that's the way you do it, you have to make sure AddToDoItemViewController doesn't get deallocated either.

It's done like this,

```
-(IBAction)pushToGeofence:(id)sender {
    if (! self.gvc) { // gvc is a property, @property (strong,nonatomic) GeofenceViewController *gvc
       self.gvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Geofence"];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.gvc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I control-dragged the + symbol button to the GeofenceTableViewController, and selected PUSH. I guess that's called a Push Segue? Doing that automatically created a "Back" button in the GeofenceTableViewController, which is what I use to go back.
Edit: Thanks a lot, I'll do a search on how to prevent the controller from being deallocated.

Comment: Is this what i'm suppoused to do? I want to be sure if that post would help me before trying, since I'm new to iOS developing. Thanks once again!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151785/viewcontroller-gets-deallocated-which-leads-to-crash

Comment: @FranciscoJavierHerrera, the way you instantiate the controller is correct in that link, but it needs to be in an if statement to check whether the property is nil (which it would be before the first time you do the push). So you check if the property is nil, if so do the instantiation, then do the push. If it's not nil, just do the push.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierHerrera, I've updated my answer with sample code.

Comment: I've implemented the code as the example shows:
<code> 
-(IBAction)pushToGeofence:(id)sender {
    if (! self.gvc) { 
        HelloWorldGeofenceViewController *gvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Geofence"];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.gvc animated:YES];
}
</code>

I've also added the property (I did all this in the HelloWorldGeofenceViewController.m file), and on my main.storyboard I removed the segue from the + button, and added the pushToGeofence method to it.

Comment: When running the app, I get a warning saying that "gvc" variable is unused, and when I tap the + button, the app crashes :/

Comment: @FranciscoJavierHerrera, that code, and the property should be in the controller that you're pushing from. Isn't that the AddToDoItemViewController?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're correct. I had added them in the HelloWorldAddToDoItemViewController, but I misspelled it here when posting the past reply. Here's a git with the source just in case https://github.com/franher007/helloWorld

Comment: @FranciscoJavierHerrera, you get the crash because you didn't add the identifier, "Geofence", to that view controller in the storyboard. The other error about the unused variable was my mistake, the code should be self.gvc = ..., not GeofenceViewController *gvc = ... I've fixed that in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed that and it's working perfectly now! One last thing, I tried to do the same with ToDoListController -> AddToDoItemController, I added the identifier "Products" to that view controller, and pointed the + button from the first view to pushToProducts, but when I tap that + button, nothing happens. Do you think you could take a look? Thanks once again, I really really appreciate it.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierHerrera, something is wrong with the way the button was hooked up to the method. Delete that connection in the storyboard, and remake it, and it should work.

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work. I even deleted the button, I added a new one, and hooked it up to a new method 
`-(IBAction)testAction:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Clicked +");
}`
but there's still no output in the debugger.
I did that the following way: Control-dragged the button to "First responder", and selected "testAction" from the menu.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierHerrera, you don't drag to the first responder, that's wrong. Control-click on the controller icon in the scene (or the controller in the list on the left of the canvas), and that will open a window which will show all the controller's connections and IBActions. Drag (not control-drag) from the open circle that's on the right side of the action to the button (if the circle is not open, delete the connection you have there now).

Comment: It's fully working now. Thank you very much! It's great to find someone who can lend you a hand when you're just starting, so I'm really thankful. Have a great week! Thank you one last time.